# Silverlight Combobox Binding to Element

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a silverlight telerik RadComboBox. I am designing a master detail page.

In the grid I have list of people - one of the columns in the grid is Salutation.
when i click on an item in the grid all the textboxes below fill according to their binding.

But with the combobox I am wondering if you can bind it like this.

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=PersonGrid, Path=SelectedItem.SalutationLookupValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Im guessing that you cannot do it this way. I would like to do it this way but im thinking that I need to bind the selecteditem to SelectedSalutation and set that when the selected item is set for the grid..

```
    public Person SelectedPersonResult
    {
        get { return _selectedPersonResult; }
        set
        {
            SetObject(ref _selectedPersonResult, value, "SelectedPersonResult");
            if (_selectedSalutationResult != null)
            {
                SelectedSalutation = SalutationList.Where(x => x.Value == SelectedPersonResult.SalutationLookupValue).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

again Id prefer to do it the first way (within the xaml) but Im guessing that doing it the second way is the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that `ComboBox` of yours behaves like the standard one the first method should work, but you should not bind to `SelectedItem`, the right property would be `SelectedValue`. (Does that combobox have such a property?)

Comment: This should work as I have done more reading online about it..but for some reason I am missing something..here is the line for the combobox <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" EmptyText="--Select Language" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=LanguageGrid, Path=SelectedItem.LanguageLookupValue, Mode=TwoWay}"></telerik:RadComboBox>

Comment: I do not have enough information about your program to know what is wrong there. Are there any binding errors?